# call multiple APIs parallel using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was thinking of a situation where we can use promise.all(), when we want to call multiple APIs parallelly, but a promise.all() rejects if any APIs get failed, but I want if any APIs gets failed I need to re-run the failed API again. but I am not getting how to approach that.
Please help me with that.

Comment: if your problem solved, accept asnwer

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to your problem is using the node library [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/). You should use particularly the method `each`

```js
const async = require("async")

// assuming openFiles is an array of file names
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

    // Perform operation on file here.
    console.log('Processing file ' + file);

    if( file.length > 32 ) {
      console.log('This file name is too long');
      callback({msg: 'File name too long', file: file });
    } else {
      // Do work to process file here
      console.log('File processed');
      callback();
    }
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      console.log('A file failed to process', err.msg, err.file);

    // try again
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

But for the issue you particularly referred to, i.e., not exit on first error, you should use `async.reflect`

> Wraps the async function in another function that always completes with a result object, even when it errors.

### Try again upon error like OP requires

```js
const callAPI = function (url, callback) {
 // do some stuff to call API
 if (error) {
   callback(error)
 } else { // success
   callback(null, url) 
 }
}

async.parallel([
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        callAPI('123.com', callback)
    }),
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        callAPI('456.com', callback)
    }),
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        callAPI('789.com', callback)
    })
],
function(err, results) {
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i].error) { // try again
            callAPI(results[i].value, {})
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: will it re-run the file processing if 1 file throws an error?

Comment: @RuchitRaj automatically not, but for that you have just to write the code in `function(err)` and repeat

Comment: lets take an example - I want to hit 3 APIs
APIs = ['123.com', '456.com', '789.com]
now suppose while calling these APIs '456.com' got failed to give the response, so what I want is again re run API('456.com') to next time may be it will give the result.

Comment: @RuchitRaj check my answer, I edited according to your issue

Comment: Your method is also very good and convenient, +1 @JoãoPimentelFerreira

Answer (score 1):

You can use The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise

It is typically used when you have multiple asynchronous tasks that are not dependent on one another to complete successfully, or you'd always like to know the result of each

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(3);
let promises = [promise1, promise2];

let removeValFromIndex = [];

function runPromises(promises) {
  Promise.allSettled(promises).then(function (results) {
    results.forEach((result, index) => {
      if (result.status == "fulfilled") {
        removeValFromIndex.push(i);
      }
      console.log(result.status);
    });
    for (var i = removeValFromIndex.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      promises.splice(removeValFromIndex[i], 1);
    if (promises.length != 0) {
      runPromises(promises);
    }
  });
}

runPromises(promises);
```

Comment: That method does not retry upon error, like OP required https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: You right, I’ll edit my answer, thank you

Comment: I updated My answer @JoãoPimentelFerreira

Comment: great, +1, I like your solution. I'd normally use nodeJS `async` module but your solution is also great.

Answer (score 0):

Generators is what you need async await runs on top of generators